# Removing unused SQLAlchemy Dialects and Tests?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm packaging SQLAlchemy, among other things, for deployment onto AWS Lambda and am looking to reduce the size of the zipped project archive. I see in `sqlalchemy/dialects` that there are a list of dialects of SQL which SQLAlchemy supports:

```
48K ./firebird
48K ./sybase
88K ./sqlite
112K    ./oracle
124K    ./mssql
204K    ./mysql
240K    ./postgresql
```

Are there any issues with removing dialects for which this project is not using? If I'm only using MySQL, I surely wouldn't need an sqlite dialect definition.

Or perhaps removing the tests under `sqlalchemy/testing`:

```
12K ./testing/engines.py
12K ./testing/fixtures.py
12K ./testing/profiling.py
16K ./testing/assertsql.py
16K ./testing/exclusions.py
16K ./testing/provision.py
20K ./testing/assertions.py
28K ./testing/requirements.py
36K ./testing/plugin
136K    ./testing/suite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a [search for the word "dialects" in the SQLAlchemy github repo](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/search?q=dialects&type=Code) and the main module that stood out was `SQLAlchemy.databases.__init__.py`:

```
from ..dialects.sqlite import base as sqlite
from ..dialects.postgresql import base as postgresql
postgres = postgresql
from ..dialects.mysql import base as mysql
from ..dialects.oracle import base as oracle
from ..dialects.firebird import base as firebird
from ..dialects.mssql import base as mssql
from ..dialects.sybase import base as sybase


__all__ = (
    'firebird',
    'mssql',
    'mysql',
    'postgresql',
    'sqlite',
    'oracle',
    'sybase',
)
```

Which I changed to:

```
from ..dialects.mysql import base as mysql


__all__ = (
    'mysql',
)
```

I also modified the `__all__` declaration in `sqlalchemy.dialects.__init__.py`. This:

```
__all__ = (
    'firebird',
    'mssql',
    'mysql',
    'oracle',
    'postgresql',
    'sqlite',
    'sybase',
)
```

to:

```
__all__ = (
    'mysql'
)
```

(*I actually don't know if modifying those `__all__` declarations is necessary. I didn't test it without doing it.*)

I then deleted all of the `sqlalchemy.dialects.*` sub directories except for `mysql` and I was able to run few MySQL CRUD apps that I have sitting around without exception.

Also deleting the `sqlalchemy.testing` folder didn't cause any problems.

I tried to run a sqllite app and got `sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:sqlite`.

So it seems that with only having to modify one or two files, you can get away with it as long as only running on the dialect that you leave behind.

The main thing is that after removing the dialects, all of the tests for your application pass (assuming your test coverage is good) as I only tested on a pretty limited set of small ORM apps.